# Symfony JWTToken change fields for generate

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I use Symfony 3.3.10 with `"lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "~2.0",` and for `user_identity_field` I use email

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%'
public_key_path:  '%jwt_public_key_path%'
pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'
user_identity_field: email
```

But after my user, call put request with `email`, I mean change email to something another. after have been change, when I call another api, example get user profile, I have error:

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unable to load an user with property \"email\" = \"q@q.com\". If the user identity has changed, you must renew the token. Otherwise, verify that the \"lexik_jwt_authentication.user_identity_field\" config option is correctly set."
}
```

I understood, because I change email, which part for generating token, but I thought token saved in session and don't need regenerate token after change email or password.

My question how to change generating token fields, example I want use some constant field, example id?

Comment: > "_but I thought token saved in session and don't need regenerate token after change email or password._"

JWT tokens are stored client side, your server doesn't remember your tokens, only validates them.

Comment: @Orange18947 ok, thnks, how to change filed for generate? Because after user change email, token invalid

Comment: Why not force users to re-login if response code = 401? This will generate a new JWT token.

Comment: yes, it's one of the way. But need tray way with another field for generate token

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to change the message 
"Unable to load an user with property \"email\" = \"q@q.com\". If the user identity has changed, you must renew the token. Otherwise, verify that the \"lexik_jwt_authentication.user_identity_field\" config option is correctly set."?

Comment: `user_identity_field` it was my contribution in this bundle after this question :))